# JavaScript short form to check if attribute exists in object

Tags: javascript

I recently got some JS code and I saw very often statements like the following:

```
if(object) {
  //do something
}
```

or

```
if(object.attr) {
      //do something
    }
```

Is this a short form for `if(object !== undefined)` or for `if(object !== null)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a short form for

```
if (object !== "" && 
    !Number.isNaN(object) &&
    object !== 0 &&
    object !== false &&
    object !== undefined &&
    object !== null)
```

The `isNaN()` check is a little tricky; the "old" global `isNaN()` would coerce its parameter to a number, so passing a string like "foo" to `isNaN()` returns `true`, even though the string "foo" isn't really `NaN`. The newer `isNaN()` method on the number constructor *doesn't* perform that coercion, so `Number.isNaN("foo")` is false.

Note that when checking for the existence of an object property there's an ambiguity with `undefined`. It's possible for a property to be present on an object but have no value. The `in` operator is useful in such cases:

```
if ("something" in object)
```

tests whether the object has a property named "something" regardless of value.